# Login/Signin via Springboot with Okta

Tags: spring, spring-security, okta, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to develop a mobile application. I will use Java in the backend. However, I confused about auth processes.

I will use okta as a authorization server. But I do not want to redirect my user to okta login page. Instead, I will create a login page and connect it to my backend service. I need to find a way that I can register user from my backend service to okta.

To summarize,

```
Client ---> Secured Spring Gateway --->  /signin (my backend service) ----> okta ( registering user) ----> back to my service so that I can save user to my db as well to relate with my other models ---> client (with provided token from okta)
```

OR

```
Client ---> Secured Spring Gateway ---> okta ( registering user) ----> /signin (my backend service)  back to my service so that I can save user to my db as well to relate with my other models ---> client (with provided token from okta)
```

I could not find any detailed example, almost all of them using okta's login form.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: What technology or framework will you be developing your mobile app with? If you want to use OIDC (which is recommended), you will have to pop a browser and redirect to Okta to login. Things are done this way so your app doesn't have access to the user's credentials. Here's a demo that shows an Ionic app that works with Face ID: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzFwl780wrE.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the login page (Okta sign in widget) yourself. Okta provides a spring boot SDK which can help you get started.

```
SDK can be found here: https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot

Sample code can be found here: https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/tree/master/custom-login
```